# Biholomorphic map between $D(0,1)\smallsetminus[0, 1)$ and the upper half plane

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I want to find a biholomorphic map between $D(0,1)\setminus[0, 1)$ and the upper half plane.

The problem is what to do with $0$. Any hint ?

Comment: $D(0,1) \setminus (0,1)$ is not open. You probably want $D(0,1) \setminus [0,1)$ instead.

Comment: This is an exercise from my exam, probably there is an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer.**
$$
f(z)=\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{z}}{1-\sqrt{z}}\right)^{\!2}\!.
$$

Step 1. The mapping $z\mapsto \sqrt{z}$, takes $D\smallsetminus [0,1)$ to $\{z\in D : \mathrm{Im}\,z>0\}$.

Step 2. The mapping $z\mapsto \left(\dfrac{1+\sqrt{z}}{1-\sqrt{z}}\right)^{\!2}$ takes $D\smallsetminus [0,1)$ to $\{z\in : \mathrm{Im}\,z>0\}$ to the upper half plane.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f_1(z)=\sqrt z$ (branch defined on $\mathbb{C}\setminus[0,\infty)$ with $\sqrt{-1}=i$.) Then $f_1\bigl(D(0,1)\setminus[0,1)\bigr)$ is the upper half of $D(0,1)$. Can you follow from here?

Comment: You probably want the *natural branch* rather than the *principal branch*.

Comment: Right. I will be more explicit.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre: ok but my set is $D(0,1) - (0,1)$

Comment: @JuliánAguirre: not $D(0,1)- [0,1)$

Comment: @WLOG  $D(0,1) - (0,1)$ is not open, so there cannot be a biholomorphic mapping between that and the upper half-plane.

Comment: @DanielFischer: you are right, I was answering to Julian